# How do I use enumServicesStatus to obtain the dwServiceType of Unknown in Windows？

Tags: c++, windows, system-information

In Windows, the `dwServiceType` of `EnumServicesStatus` has no "Unknown" attribute.  Only SERVICE_DRIVER, SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER, SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, SERVICE_WIN32, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, and SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS are defined. Failure is returned if any other value is used.

See this picture showing an "Unknown" type:
[image: Screen capture showing unknown service type]

Comment: All values not listed as a documented dwServiceType are treated as "Unknown".

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer. When I use dwServiceType in enumServicesStatus, Only SERVICE_DRIVER, SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER, SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, SERVICE_WIN32, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, and SERVICE_WIN3 are defined 2_SHARE_PROCESS. Failure is returned if any other value is used.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I assumed that was the "Status" column. (I don't read Chinese, so I just guessed.) An online translator says that the column heading is "Service type" but I don't see any such column when I run Task Manager and go to the Services tab.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [EnumServicesStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-enumservicesstatusw#parameters) are incomplete in their list of `dwServiceType` values.  The complete list of bits available in the bitmask can be found in [`winnt.h`](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/cb33d402bb7fc44a51cd96adfbe740d4b2d7a134/include/winnt.h#L5977-L5992). One version I found, which appears to be older, is:

```c
/* Service types */
#define SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER      0x00000001
#define SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER 0x00000002
#define SERVICE_ADAPTER            0x00000004
#define SERVICE_RECOGNIZER_DRIVER  0x00000008

#define SERVICE_DRIVER ( SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER | SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER | \
                         SERVICE_RECOGNIZER_DRIVER )

#define SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS   0x00000010
#define SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS 0x00000020
#define SERVICE_WIN32  (SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS | SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS)

#define SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS 0x00000100

#define SERVICE_TYPE_ALL ( SERVICE_WIN32 | SERVICE_ADAPTER | \
                           SERVICE_DRIVER | SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS )
```

Raymond Chen indicates in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76701369/how-do-i-use-enumservicesstatus-to-obtain-the-dwservicetype-of-unknown-in-window#comment135266164_76724783) that 0x40 is `SERVICE_USER_SERVICE` in newer versions of Windows.

The presence of "Unknown" indicates there must be a default condition for service types not included in the header file, likely due to changes in newer versions of Windows.

In the case of the particular Agent Activation Runtime (Aarsvc) in your image, the type is 96 (0x60 = 0x40 | 0x20), which appears in other documentation as `USER_SHARE_PROCESS` (see [Per User Services Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/per-user-services-in-windows)), and is not in the list of values above.  Type 80 (0x50 = 0x40 | 0x10, `USER_OWN_PROCESS`) also fits into that category, a per user service that's an "own" process rather than a shared one.

So it seems searching using `SERVICE_USER_SERVICE | SERVICE_WIN32` should return at least that particular service; perhaps not all unknowns.

For more possible "Unknown" values, see [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/osquery/osquery/issues/6852) listing the following:

```cpp
const std::map<int, std::string> kServiceType = {
    {0x00000001, "Driver"},
    {0x00000002, "FS driver"},
    {0x00000010, "OWN_PROCESS"},
    {0x00000020, "SHARE_PROCESS"},
    {0x00000100, "INTERACTIVE_PROCESS"},
    {0x00000110, "OWN_PROCESS(Interactive)"},
    {0x00000120, "SHARE_PROCESS(Interactive)"},
    {0x00000050, "USER_OWN_PROCESS"},
    {0x000000d0, "USER_OWN_PROCESS(Instance)"},
    {0x00000060, "USER_SHARE_PROCESS"},
    {0x000000e0, "USER_SHARE_PROCESS(Instance)"},
    {0x00000210, "PACKAGE_OWN_PROCESS"},
    {0x00000220, "PACKAGE_SHARE_PROCESS"}
};
```

This indicates a `0x200` bitmask associated with packages and a `0xc0` bitmask associated with instances as well.

Comment: There is a new flag `#define SERVICE_USER_SERVICE 0x00000040` that explains the `0x00000040`. It's in the latest header file but the documented hasn't caught up.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks! I updated my answer.  Seems there's also a `0x200` associated with packages, and a `0xc0` associated with instances as well.